# clr-tree-node selection not effect collapsed child nodes

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

I've build a component based on Clarity (v 0.13.1) Tree view,

I have an issue when i am selecting\ unselecting a collapsed parent node,
it's not affecting child nodes selection, 
and when i'm expanding him he is getting selected\unselected again.

Can someone assist please?

below is the view:

```
<clr-tree-node class="tree-root" [(clrSelected)]="tree.selected" id="statusTreeFilter">
{{tree.name}}
<ng-template [(clrIfExpanded)]="tree.expanded">
  <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let group of tree.childs" [(clrSelected)]="group.selected">
    <span>{{group.name}}</span>
    <ng-template [(clrIfExpanded)]="group.expanded">
      <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let status of group.childs" [(clrSelected)]="status.enable">
        <span>{{status.name}}</span>
        <ng-template></ng-template>
      </clr-tree-node>
    </ng-template>
  </clr-tree-node>
</ng-template>
```

and Data:

```
let tree = {
"name": "All",
"selected": true,
"expanded": false,
"childs": [
  {
    "name": "Generate",
    "selected": true,
    "expanded": false,
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "Init",
        "enable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Generating",
        "enable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Generated",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Printing",
    "selected": true,
    "expanded": false,
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "Printing",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Finalized",
    "selected": true,
    "expanded": false,
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "Completed",
        "enable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Cancelled",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed on clarity 1.0 (breaking changes)

[See ticket here](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/2859)

Answer (score 0):

Your root node needs to point to the boolean `selected` property of the `selection` object. You're setting the clrSelected binding to the whole object, which causes this behavior.

```
<clr-tree-node class="tree-root" [(clrSelected)]="selection.selected" id="statusTreeFilter">
```

Here it is setup fully. https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-hmrndh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i have already tried your suggestion, and it isn't  helping,
you can see this behavior in you'r example too, when you selecting\ unselecting a collapsed parent node, he's selection changes when you expand it.

Comment: You must have misunderstood something about the question because your example behaves just as the OP described. That is, child nodes are not getting affected by the parent's selection correctly.

Comment: Ok, so I see the collapsed state issue now that I read it again. It helps to provide a working example, and the fix I've described is still necessary to get it to work at all. However, this is an open issue see https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1400

Comment: Thanks @JeremyWilken,
It seems like this bug is on hold, do you know when it will be fixed?

Comment: We're looking at understanding use cases better, so feel free to explain your use case in that ticket.